# How to highlight a cell in Excel if it does not match another cell? (And apply that conditional formatting to an entire column)

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

I have two columns of data in Excel. The first column shows start times, and the second column shows an end times. I want to highlight any START time cell (first column) if it does **not** match the previous END time cell (specifically the cell one row up and one column to the right).

[image: screenshot]

In my screenshot example, I want to highlight cell A6 because it does not match cell B5. I have successfully done this for specific cell pairings, but I can't figure out how to apply this conditional formatting to the entire column, so that future start times that are entered incorrectly can be highlighted automatically. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Highlight column A.  Conditional formatting.  New Rule.  Use a formula to determine which cells to format.

For Format values where this value is true, enter:

```
 =AND($A2<>$B1,NOT(ISBLANK($A2)),NOT(ISBLANK($B1)))
```

Pretty straight forward.  Check for formatting, but only format if cells are populated.

Comment: That result does not appear to achieve the outcome requested, there is no requirement to check if they are blank, the formula needs to check if they are equal to each other.

Comment: @JustinDoward Eliminates false positives.   Just need column A, actually.

Comment: Also should change A2<B1 to read A2=B1, I missed the point of the isblank initially but I was just looking for something that checked the cells were equal. Anyway, simple enough for Jenna to change the symbol.

Comment: @JustinDoward Not sure what you mean.  OP has cases where data is equal, but not highlighed.  They want to highlight when data is entered incorrectly.

Comment: Ah, again, so should be <>, obviously my reply to this was unnecessary in the first instance, just looked at it all too quick. The OP does not seem to be returning anyway.